# With modernizing-oauth-interactions, can googleplus sign in auth token be used in google realtime apis?

Tags: cordova, oauth, inappbrowser, google-drive-realtime-api

Background for this question is this --> [Modernizing OAuth interactions in Native Apps for Better Usability and Security](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

In any mobile app using inappbrowser, Oauth requests will be restricted 
But can we use Google plus sign in and use its Auth token in rtcclient JS APIs??

Comment: Guys, I tried using Google plus sign in APIs. And its working fine. Able to migrate successfully out of InAppBrowser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were alternatives suggested in that blog itself

> To help you migrate, we offer libraries and samples that follow modern
>   best practices which you can use:
>
> 1. Google Sign-In for Android and iOS, our recommended SDK for sign-in
>      and OAuth with Google Accounts.
> 2. AppAuth for Android, iOS, and OS X, an
>      open source OAuth client library that can be used with Google and
>      other OAuth providers. We also offer GTMAppAuth (for iOS and OS X), a
>      library which enables AppAuth support for the Google APIs Client
>      Library for Objective-C, and the GTM Session Fetcher projects.
> 3. Google Sign-in and OAuth Examples for Windows, examples demonstrating how to
>      use the browser to authenticate Google users in various Windows
>      environments such as Universal Windows Platform (UWP), console and
>      desktop apps.

First alternative is basic APIs which can be used in any Android and IOS Apps
I did not investigate much on second and third alternative

Based on first alternative, there is a plugin available for Cordova apps, *cordova-plugin-googleplus*, it provides basic login, logout features.
On IOS, it provides refreshToken and accessToken directly after login
but on Android, fetching refreshToken and accessToken is not supported in the plugin